# Create variable using a string + second variable

Tags: powershell, variables

In the beginning of this script I've set some variables ($numof0 = 3, $numof1 = 5, etc.). I'd like to write all those variables to the console, but I would like to be more consise than the 10 write-host statements below.

```
Write-Host "There are $numOf0 0's"
Write-Host "There are $numOf1 1's"
Write-Host "There are $numOf2 2's"
Write-Host "There are $numOf3 3's"
Write-Host "There are $numOf4 4's"
Write-Host "There are $numOf5 5's"
Write-Host "There are $numOf6 6's"
Write-Host "There are $numOf7 7's"
Write-Host "There are $numOf8 8's"
Write-Host "There are $numOf9 9's"
```

I figured since all the variables have the same beginning ($numof) and all end with an increasing number, I could do something like this..

```
$j=0
while($j -lt 10){
    $final = '$numof'+"$j"
    write-host "There are $final $j's"
    $j++
}
```

Obviously the variable $final is just a string though, and when printed to the console does not show the contents of the corresponding $numofX variable I'd like printed.

Is there a way to create one variable ($final) using a string and another variable (string '$numof' and variable '$j') and still have it reference the original contents of the $numOfX variable?

Comment: Set/New-Variable will do the trick, but for the love of future generations please use a hashtable or an array

Comment: Ah good call. Array it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-Expression?view=powershell-5.1) can evaluate your string as if it were typed as a command

```
$j=0
while($j -lt 10){
    $final = Invoke-Expression -Command ('$numof'+"$j")
    write-host "There are $final $j's"
    $j++
}
```